# jQuery .addClass() working only after enabling debuggers tool in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

```
tableContanier.find("#openLink").addClass("hide");
```

Above code works fine when I enable the debuggers tool. There are many places where I have used .addClass() but only for a case this happens. After a ajax call, entire table is repainted and then this code of a function gets executed. The same code executes well for the first time.

Comment: Is the code in the ajax success function?

Comment: Are you setting a breakpoint maybe giving the ajax call enough time to complete when you are in debug mode?

Comment: Do you have any `console.log` commands in your code? They will blow up on non-debug IE unless you have a shim in place.

Comment: Also, is it spelled `tableContanier` or, correctly, as `tableContainer`?

Comment: @Spokey :  yes its inside ajax success.

Comment: @Ernesto : NO, I am not setting any breakpoint, I'm not starting the debugging even, just pressing F12 and it starts working.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Spelling is not the issue and yes there is a console.log code in the calling method. if(window.console) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that `tableContanier` has lost it's reference after the ajax call. Not sure if/why the debugger tool would have anything to do with that.

Regardless, if you're using valid HTML, then just using `$('#openLink')` should do the trick since there should only be one "openLink" id on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Comment as answer for now:

Do you have any `console.log()` commands in your code? They will blow up on non-debug version of IE as `console` does not exist *unless you have the debug window open*.

If this is the case, you can always have a *shim* in place like the one below at the start of your code.

```
if (!window.console) {
    window.console = {
        log: $.noop          // point log at the "do nothing" function in jQuery
    };
}
```